# Writing the most efficient MongoDB multi index query that returns only unique _ids matching all queried indexes?

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization, mongo-shell

I'm trying to write a pattern recognition query that doesn't read any documents in the collection but rather uses multiple covered individual indices. For example, I would like to query three indices of three separate properties against three operator statements. So something like this:

We create an index for each property: x, y, z (all numbers) then query:

`x: { $gte: 500 }`   // Returns _id: 1, 5, 9, 30, 45

`y: { $gte: 10000 }` // Returns _id: 1, 5, 9, 28, 30, 47, 41, 45

`z: { $gte: 1000 }`  // Returns _id: 1, 9, 30, 37, 42, 45

return ONLY the unique _id's that match all three property searches: 1, 9, 30, 45

I am using NodeJS client SDK but MongoDB terminal (mongosh) commands could be helpful too!

**Performance is a huge factor**, I need to search over millions/billions of records in >100ms at least preferably >50ms. The idea is to run this query as often as the database is capable, so the faster the better. It will never stop querying, just the parameters of the query will change.

I do not want to run the risk of maxing out either the indexes or the query functions .distinct() has some limitations if I understand it right? New to MongoDB has a SQL background. This is the first performance first project I have tackled. Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Any links to documentation are more than welcome, my question is more about theory and understanding how to leverage MongoDB to increase performance than specific code examples. Although those are more than welcome!

Comment: [Indexing Strategies](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/indexes/#indexing-strategies).

Comment: @prasad_ I have read that through, thank you for the link it didn't answer my question but it was helpful in understanding why indexes are useful for performance.